# Drag a view onLongClick and start activity onClick

Tags: java, android, motionevent, onlongclicklistener, ontouch

I'm banging my head with this problem which probably is simple but since I'm new to this topic I somehow haven't been able to figure it out yet.

I've successfully implemented dragging a view with `onTouch` method. I've also successfully implemented `onLongClick` and `onClick` methods. But both of these functionalities were implemented separately.

The problem, like the title says is when I want to join these functionalities. I want the `onTouch` method to be called when a user long clicks a view and I want a new activity to start when a user clicks a view.

Here is the pseudo code:

```
  public class Website extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener{

    TextView longpress;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_website);

    longpress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longpress);
    longpress.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view){
           //I don't really know how to do this part
           onTouch(View view, Motion Event event);
           return true;
        }
    });
    longpress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            //Code for new activity comes here (I know how to do this part)
        }
    });
    }

     public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction(){
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                //Save initial coordinates of view <-- view.getX(), view.getY() 
                break;
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                //Calculate dX and dY and setX and Y of the view (move view)
                break;
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                //If view is certain distance away from initial points do something
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Like I said, `onTouch` works on itself if I don't try to call it from `onLongClick` method. If I try to call `onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)` from `onLongClick` method **the problem occurs because `onLongClick` only receives one out of two arguments `onTouch` method should receive** (`onLongClick` only receives view argument but it should also receive event argument).

Maybe I'm trying to do this in a totally wrong way but I have been looking at some documentation e.g. https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/ but still won't get an idea what to do.

(I would like to have a similar functionality to notifications on android phones)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've come to a solution which might or might not be a good one but for now it serves my functionality. If someone has a better solution and thinks mine is bad in some way please say so.

Here is the code:

```
boolean flag;
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event){
    int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
        if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            //do something on a down press
            flag = true;
            return true;
        }
        if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && flag == true){
            //do something if we move finger away from screen we 
            //didn't move the view first

            return true;
        }
        if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && flag == false){
            //do something if we move finger away from screen and we moved 
            //the view before we moved the finger away from screen
        }
        if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            //do something when moving the view
            flag = false;
        }
```